# Differentiating the adverbs of frequency

Tags: grammar

I can't tell the difference in meaning between the following since to me they all define doing something frequently:
a)我经常在图书馆学习。
b)我一般在图书馆学习。
c）我总是在图书馆学习。
If I want to say,"I usually study at the library",do all the above apply or is there a nuanced difference in meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you understand the English words, you should have no problem with choosing which words in what context

- "**经常**" = "**often**": once in a while or once every few days is considered "often"
- "**一般**" = "**normally**": when you are not doing it, it is considered abnormal, in other words, you do it almost every time but with occasional exceptions
- "**总是**" = "**always**": you are expected to do it every time, extremely rare to have exceptions
- "**通常**" = "**usually**": when you are not doing it, it is considered unusual, in other words, you do it almost every time but with occasional exceptions

通常(usually/ normally) ; 一般(normally)

> "I usually study at the library" = "我通常在图书馆学习"

Comment: Out of interest, how do you differentiate "usually" and "normally"?

Comment: "usually" and "normally" are about the same frequency. See my edition

Answer (score 0):

(a) 我**经常**在图书馆学习。

(b) 我**一般**在图书馆学习。

(c) 我**总是**在图书馆学习。

What is the difference between **经常, 一般, 总是**?

The word **经常** is for frequency, the same as "often". In sentence (a), it modifies the verb "学习". It answers a question like "不上课的时候，你在学校**干什么**?" = "What do you do in school when there is no class"?

The word **一般** modifies the phrase 在图书馆. Sentence (b) answers a question like "你平常在**哪里**学习?" = "Where do you study usually?"

The word **总是** also modifies the phrase 在图书馆 but it implies that the fact is exclusively true. Sentence (c) could be in a dialogue like "我每次到你的教室找你，你都不在." =  "I could not meet you every time I go to your classroom"?

In many situations, people use these words interchangeably. As you may see, language is not always exact.